# Java SwingWorker with same instance of Class?

Tags: java, swing, swingworker, opennlp

I have a few SwingWorkers running and they all need OpenNLP for calculation.
OpenNLP needs some time for initialisation so I wonder what's the best way doing this?
I guess it's not smart to start one instance of OpenNLP in every SwingWorker.
I could initialise one instance and passing it to every SwingWorker but the problem is that I can/want initalise OpenNLP only in the SwingWorkers and not before.

So I want to start all Workers in a loop and after start they (or just one of them?) should init die instance of OpenNLP. When it's ready every Worker should use it.

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have all swing workers use a single factory bean that does synchronized lazy initialization:

```
public class OpenNLPFactory {

  public synchronized OpenNLP getOpenNLP() {
      if(OpenNLP ready )  { 
          return it
      } else {
          build it and return it.
     }
  }

}
```

The OpenNLP object returned will itself have to be thread safe of course...